# MySQL exclude data clauyse

Tags: mysql, sql

Say, we have data from every months of year 2000 to year 2007, I'd like to exclude all the data of June 2007.

My way is to include the data from 2000 to 2006, and all months of 2007 except June.

```
WHERE yearnumber IN (2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006) 
      OR 
      ( yearnumber = 2007 AND monthnumber <> 6)
```

Here is my problem, what if we have a huge number of years, which means I have to type in every yearnumber in IN clause. **Is there a simple way of excluding data of June 2007?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Just use `NOT`:

```
where not (yearnumber = 2007 and monthnumber = 6)
```

or the equivalent:

```
where yearnumber <> 2007 or monthnumber <> 6
```

I think the first is logically easier to follow.

Comment: True. Thanks. I couldn't give a upvote due to newly registered account.